# Are there any pitfalls to simulate defaulted function parameters using aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, c++20, designated-initializer

### Question:

If you want, for example, a variadic function that takes arbitrary number of parameter `Args&&...args`, and prints all those arguments `t` times. What's more is that you want `t` to be defaulted to `1`, so it prints all `args` one time by default.

The first thing you would try is:

```cpp
template <typename ... Args>
void foo(Args... args, unsigned t = 1) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        (std::cout << ... << args);
    }
}
```

Apparently this doesn't work unless you explicitly pass in the template parameters:

```cpp
// Error: expected 1 argument, got 2
foo(0, "Hello, world!");
```

Because default parameters are treated as normal parameters while template deduction, and the parameter pack would always be empty. This prevents you from making the function useful. ([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805192/c-variadic-template-function-parameter-with-default-value))

I then decided to use aggregate initialization (especially [designated initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) since c++ 20) to simulate a more powerful "default parameter". It looks like this:

```cpp
struct foo_t {
    unsigned t = 1;
    template <typename ... Args>
    void operator() (Args... args) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
            (std::cout << ... << args);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    foo_t{}("Hello, ", "World!\n");      // prints 1 line
    foo_t{ 5 }(0, "Hello, world!\n");    // prints 5 lines
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, this may solve people's complaint that they cannot "skip" default function parameters, with the help of c++ 20 designated intializers:

```cpp
struct bar_t {
    const std::string& str = "Hello, world!";
    int t = 1;
    void operator() () {
        for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // Skips .str, using the default "Hello, World!"
    bar_t{ .t = 10 }();
    return 0;
}
```

**I am wondering whether there are any potential pitfalls to do this.**

### Background (Can be safely ignored)

So yesterday I was wandering around SO and encountered a question (but it was later deleted) that asked about how to combine default `std::source_location` parameter with variadic template:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void log(Args&&... args, const std::experimental::source_location& location = std::experimental::source_location::current()) {
    std::cout << location.line() << std::endl;
}
```

Apparently this does not work as expected, just as stated in the question. So I came up with the following code:

```cpp
struct logger {
    const std::experimental::source_location& location = std::experimental::source_location::current();
    template <typename... Args>
    void operator() (Args&&... args) {
        std::cout << location.line() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    logger{}("I passed", argc, "arguments.");
    return 0;
}
```

But found out it can do more, thus this question.

Comment: OT: Another solution might be to employ tuples: [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qicey6Ij1R33dZQA).

Comment: My question is not deleted, it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57547273 :)

Comment: @L.F. Oh I was referring to another question, not yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one pitfall with lifetime (extension):

`const std::string& str = "Hello, world!";` create dangling pointer, (No lifetime extension for member).

Following is fine:

```
void repeat_print(const std::string& str = "Hello, world!", int t = 1) {/*..*/}

int main()
{
    repeat_print();
}
```

but following is not:

```
struct bar_t {
    const std::string& str = "Hello, world!";
    int t = 1;
    void operator() () const { /*..*/ }
};

int main()
{
    bar_t{}();
}
```

You might fix `bar_t` to take member by value, but then you would do extra copy in some cases.

Comment: Interesting. I checked the standard (n4830). It says `a temporary expression bound to a reference member from a default member initializer is ill-formed`. So my code is actually ill-formed? (although all major compilers accept it, with `clang` giving a warning about dangling-reference)

Comment: What if I do `const std::string& str = []() -> auto& { thread_local const std::string& ret = "Hello, World!"; return ret; }();`?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin: That works, but why not just make a static class member for the default and save the damage to your soul?

Comment: @DavisHerring To make sure that it only get initialized when the function is called?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin: Why does that matter?  Is the cost of one `std::string` (that probably isn’t even using the heap) significant?  Does the timing of its construction affect anything?

Comment: `std::string_view` fix issue in current case. In general case, referencing (lazy) static variable would work too (but seems too verbose and easy to forget). My preference would go to CTAD of linked question.