# Clang doesn't allow variadic arguments after default parameter, gcc does

Tags: c++, templates, clang, variadic-templates

I have this declaration:

```cpp
    template<class... Types>
    static void DispatchCompute(
        EffectFramework& frame_work,
        const std::string& shader_path,
        const std::vector<GpuDataBufferInfo<VulkanImage*>>& textures,
        const std::vector<GpuDataBufferInfo<VulkanBuffer>>& buffers,
        const Eigen::Vector3i& work_groups = {1, 0, 0},
        const Types&... args);
```

And lower down I have the definition. Gcc compiles this code just fine, but clang errors with:

```
error: missing default argument on parameter 'args' const Types&... args)
```

As far as I know the above is perfectly valid C++, you can add a variadic list after a default argument. I am not sure how to circumvent the error.

Comment: I have no idea what (if anything) the "standard" says. 
 But there are practical issues. 
 Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805192), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33672904/421195) and [here](https://www.cppstories.com/2021/non-terminal-variadic-args/) for discussion, and potential workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, however, as far as I can see those are about having default values in thr variadic list, and they all involve complicated use of templates, which highly obfuscates the logic. :\

Comment: Which version are you using? clang >= 11 seems working https://godbolt.org/z/Ksj9fhdM1

Comment: Seems I am using this version:
`clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 `

Comment: Yes, I did not find that when i first searched, this is then a duplicate